# Search for multiple words in a file, and for each file print on 1 line - bash

Tags: bash

Currently I am using the following command to search for 2 words in a file:

```
grep -r -e word1 -e word2
```

This loops recursively through all subdirectories, finds which files have word1, word2 (currently all files have both word1 and word2), and prints the lines that match. The problem is when it finds word1, it prints a newline with the filename that it found and the line. Then when it finds word2, it prints a newline with the filename that it found and the line. So the filename is printed twice.

So the output would be something like this:

```
file1: word1 ... rest of line
file1: word2 ... rest of line
```

But I want something like this:

```
file1: word1 ... rest of line    word2 ... rest of line
```

Where the whitespace in between word1 and word2 could be a tab or some other delimeter.

I don't want to parse my original output and have to merge the lines together manually. I am looking for a command to do this in 1 go using bash.

Comment: What if word1 appears twice (on different lines) in file1 and word2 twice too? Should that be accumulated on a single output line with four tab-separated results?

Comment: For the purpose of this question I know the exact layout of all the files. They follow a certain format and the situation you described won't happen. There will only be 1 "word1" and 1 "word2". They're not words, they're unique strings

Answer (score 0):

If it is guaranteed that each file will have one and only one match for each word, you can do this:

```
grep -r -e word1 -e word2 <directory> | paste -d " "  - -
```

Comment: @Michael `man paste` will do a much better job that I'd do here :)